# Free memory of chells from 3 dimensional array in C when i dont need them anymore

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

i have so far this code and i have a problem with memory that my 3 dimensional array uses (program stop working)

```
       int i,j;
       int ms=10000;
       int ns=10000;
       int (*3DArray)[ms][ms] = calloc( ms, sizeof *3DArray );
       if(!S){printf("memory problem");}
       counter=1;
         for (i=0 ; i<=ms ; i++ )      {
           for (j=0 ; j<=ns ; j++ )    {
             if (...statement..) {
             3DArray[i][i][counter]=j;
             counter++;          }
             else {
             free(3DArray);}      
                                       }} //end of for
```

*At the first phase,I'm trying to check if statment(line 9) is false so free/delete memory of the useless cell(s)...*

Then in phase 2 I'm trying to free 2-step behind the present i my array for to reduce the amount of memory that C uses and my program finaly work.

```
       int i,j;
       int ms=10000;
       int ns=10000;
       int (*3DArray)[ms][ms] = calloc( ms, sizeof *3DArray );
       if(!S){printf("memory problem");}
       counter=1;
         for (i=0 ; i<=ms ; i++ )      {
           for (j=0 ; j<=ns ; j++ )    {
             if (...statement..) {
             3DArray[i][i][counter]=j;
             counter++;          }
             else {
                   if(i>2)//so if i'm have arlready pass 3 times
                   free(3DArray[i-2]);}//delete the part of 3DArray that its 2 times before
                                       //that is useless anymore
                                       }} //end of for
```

Am I just a little close with this that I want to do, or free() cant help me with that? Thanks

Comment: What is 3DArray?  It isn't even a valid identifer.

Comment: @Tom Karzes 3DArray is a 3 dimensional array that have ms^3 size... But only some points its usefull from me every time(but i find them in that if) so i want to free all the unusefull memory cells

Comment: @xing i try with realoc but i cant delete memory of particulars cells when i dont need them in the (for loop) for example i may want to keep 3DArray[10][34][1] but all the other cells like 3DArray[10][...][...] are unusefull, i try with realoc and i didnt make it for this that i need.

Comment: Then maybe you need to think about a different data structure to model your problem.

Comment: Every section of memory freed by free() must be allocated with a separate malloc/calloc call. While [this primer](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/) is for 2D arrays, it's easy to expand the concepts to 3D arrays. Ex 2 is the closest to what you need to do to be able to free individual portions.